# check if character is a punctuation

Tags: java

Program to check if the first character in the string is a punctuation and if it is, delete that character and return the new word.

```
public static String checkStart(String word){
    char [] punctuation = {'.' , ',' , ';' , ':', '?' , '!' , '"' , '\'' , ')' , '('};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < punctuation.length;i++){
        if(word.charAt(0) == punctuation[i]){
            word = word.substring(1);
        }    
    }
    return word;
}
```

Why is it not working?

here is it method caller

```
public static String[] removePunctuation(String [] words){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < words.length;i++){
        words[i] = checkStart(words[i]);
    }
    return words;
}
```

}

Comment: See your punctuation array problem is with that.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The program will run but it will give an exception of NullPointerException

and it doesn't delete the first character ,adasd will still be ,asdasd

Comment: Post the code you have which calls this method.

Comment: Have you checked that your code compiles? `removePunctuation` does not match with `checkStart` and they both accept different argument types, `String[]` _vs_ `String`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(checkStart(",abcd"));
}
```

output:

```
abcd
```

You probably have an error in your **main** method.

Answer (score 1):

> Program to check if the first character in the string is a punctuation

This actually doesn't quite do that. Think about what happens if you enter ".,;Hello" - in this case, you'll get back "Hello". On the other hand, if you enter ";,.Hello", you'll get back ",.Hello" - this is because you go through the array in sequence, and in the first case the punctuation is in the right order for each symbol to be caught, but in the second case, neither the comma nor the period is in position zero when you are looking at the punctuation[0] or punctuation[1]. I'm not sure whether one of these behaviors is what you're finding to be wrong, but I think at least one of them is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into my netbeans, and it seems to run fine:

```
public class Test{
    public static String checkStart(String word){
        char [] punctuation = {'.' , ',' , ';' , ':', '?' , '!' , '"' , '\'' , ')' , '('};
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < punctuation.length;i++){
            if(word.charAt(0) == punctuation[i]){
                word = word.substring(1);
            }    
        }
        return word;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(checkStart("test"));
        System.out.println(checkStart("!test"));
        System.out.println(checkStart(";test"));
        System.out.println(checkStart("(test"));
    }
}
```

This had the output of:

Test

Test

Test

Test

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly, but I think you want to get strings after some of specific characters.
So I changed code like below.

```
package org.owls.test;

public class CheckStart {
    private static String checkStart(String word){
        char [] punctuation = {'.' , ',' , ';' , ':', '?' , '!' , '"' , '\'' , ')' , '('};
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < punctuation.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++){
                if(word.charAt(j) == punctuation[i]){
                    word = word.substring(j);
                }    
            }
        }
        return word;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkStart("gasf;dgjHJK"));
    }
}
```

So you can get ';dgjHJK' as returns. If there are multiple keywords and you want to substring from only first, you add `break;` to second loop in checkStart.

Have a good day!

Comment: if you want after ';' you change 'j' to 'j+1' in substring parameter